# Write hex code to text file from integer value in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, integer, hex, ubuntu-14.04

**Details: Ubuntu 14.04(LTS), Python(2.7)**

I want to write hex code to a text file so I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np

width = 28    
height = 28
num = 10

info = np.array([num, width, height]).reshape(1,3)
info = info.astype(np.int32)

newfile = open('test.txt', 'w')
newfile.write(info)
newfile.close()
```

I expected like this:

```
00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 1C
```

But this is my actual result:

```
0A 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00
```

Why did this happen and how can I get my expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want big endian binary data, call `astype(">i")` then `tostring()`:

```
import numpy as np

width = 28    
height = 28
num = 10

info = np.array([num, width, height]).reshape(1,3)
info = info.astype(np.int32)
info.astype(">i").tostring()
```

If you want hex text:

```
" ".join("{:02X}".format(x) for x in info.astype(">i").tostring())
```

the output:

```
00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 1C
```